# Recover Data from formatted Windows 7 OS

Tags: hard-drive, restore

Actually my system had dual OS.one is Windows7 and Ubuntu 10.10.
But while installing debian based linux on my system,i formatted both OS.I want to recover all data of my hard disk.

please suggest ideas/solution for me.

My system Configuration
4GB-RAM
500GB-SATA HDD

Comment: If I were in your place, I wouldn't touch the HDD with any software or even power it on. What I would do would be disconnecting it from the motherboard right away and bringing it to a data restoration company for a payed service, sure only if I had any valuable data to restore.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ontrack data recovery and ntfs they are power recovery tools with advance format recovery option and be assure when you format you drive the block are net set null......

Comment: Free data recovery software is a great deal better: http://www.piriform.com/recuva/download then paid shovelware.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ontrack EasyRecovery Professional 6.2 - Advanced Recovery, ignore MFT, or use MFT 2 table.
Or use R-Studio 5+ or 6+ version.

The basic idea is to find the $MFT or a copy, $MFT2. In an extreme case, ignore the file table. The most severe variant search files of a certain type of information without the use of the file table. Good luck, make a backup.